# How to make Cucumber/Capybara close or quit the browser session after test execution is complete?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I am having some issues in Jenkins. After test execution completes, the browser session is still alive, which is creating some other issue in the pipeline. So I want to quit the browser session after execution completed in my Test Suite. I am using Cucumber>Capybara>SitePrism>Ruby.

How I can do that? I want something like below which will execute after very end of my test suite:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:suite) do
    puts 'Destroy Driver'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please format your code when posting a question.

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara

Comment: How can i format? I was trying to do that a lot...

Comment: Using Phantomjs.     
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :phantomjs, desired_capabilities: { 'phantomjs.cli.args' => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
Capybara.send(:session_pool).each { |name, ses| ses.driver.quit }
```

which should call quit on every instance of Selenium::Webdriver, however that is accessing the private method sesion_pool, and really those instances should just automatically get cleaned up when capybara exits unless you're doing something strange with sessions (or maybe there's a bug in selenium when used with phantomjs).

Comment: Got this below Error:
                                                                                                            undefined method `quit' for ["selenium:default:8", #<Capybara::Session>]:Array (NoMethodError)

Comment: this could also cause problems if there are good sessions running in parallel ex: [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/)

Comment: @SaeeK you are calling quit on the session_pool object instead of looping through and calling it on the session objects in the collection.  Check your code the provided code should work.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for folks coming here from their internet searches.

Use the [`quit` instance method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#quit-instance_method) defined by [Capybara::Session](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session).

I found two ways to hit this:

1. If you're using `Capybara::DSL` directly (e.g. in a plain ruby script like I am), `current_scope.session.quit` does the trick.
2. Or, [`Capybara.current_session.quit`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara#current_session-class_method) is probably what you need in an RSpec hook since the `Capybara::Session` methods won't be mixed in there.

Note: The original question seems a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I've never had to manually close Capybara sessions after tests and it makes me think there's some other configuration error or other problem getting in the way. Considering the OP is 5 years old however, this is a moot point, although I figured I'd mention it for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 0):

Try using - [Capybara.reset_sessions!](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.reset_sessions!)

Comment: Thanks for this Sanchita. I have already Implemented this for resetting sessions. My Question was How Driver got killed after test execution completes? Is that taken care by Capybara? If not Then we can kill the driver explicitly.

Comment: this method seems to only clear session data like cookies and doesn't close the session.

Answer (score 0):

After trying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67359080/7573223) I got unsatisfactory results. I believe this is because quitting the session is defined as => Disconnect from the current driver. So the driver will still be there and will eventually be handled by the configuration of Capybara and your Driver.

I got improved results with: [Capybara.current_session.driver.quit](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Selenium/Driver#quit-instance_method).

I am using Selenium so it calls the Driver's quit method, Which has the following source:

```rb
def quit
  @browser&.quit
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError, Errno::ECONNREFUSED,
       Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSessionIdError
  # Browser must have already gone
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError => e
  unless silenced_unknown_error_message?(e.message) # Most likely already gone
    # probably already gone but not sure - so warn
    warn "Ignoring Selenium UnknownError during driver quit: #{e.message}"
  end
ensure
  @browser = nil
end
```

But still was having issues. which lead me to the XY problem comment from the answer that I tried and so far have landed on a configuration change that seems to have helped a lot.

I am using Selenium Grid from [a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/seleniarm/standalone-chromium) and found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594007/7573223) =>  which prompted the `driver.quit` approach but later lead to wanting to update the `-cleanUpCycle` parameter

This lead me dig through the [docs and find](https://github.com/seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm?tab=readme-ov-file#grid-url-and-session-timeout) an ENV variable `SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT` that handles the same functionality of `-cleanUpCycle`. setting a low `SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT` in tandem with increasing `SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS` to at least 2, I could then have my stale session with availability to start up the next session while the short session timeout cleans up the stale session before I can make a 3rd request for another session.

#### NOTE:

This is obviously not an answer for everyone who is having problems with your sessions but while you may be using a different driver, the concept could be worth trying with your driver's configuration.